# AWS ECR GetAuthorizationToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I've tried to follow AWS instructions on setting ECR authorization to my user by giving the `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` policy to my user.

However when I try to run on my PC the `aws ecr get-login` I get an error that I don't have permission.

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:user/MY_USER is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *
```

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: MFA can also cause this issue

Comment: you can use 'aws sts get-caller-identity'. Returns details about the IAM user or role whose credentials are used to call the operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found out that when 2FA is enabled there is no option to use the aws ecr get-login, once I've removed the 2FA from my account I got the authorization token

Comment: aws get-session-token  can get a token from MFA - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html

Comment: if you have setup 2FA and used a custom aws profile in your local .aws/credentials file you have to provide the name of this profile you want to use. In my case i have a profile named "MFA" so i have to add a "--profile mfa" to almost every command. Or you can "export AWS_PROFILE=mfa" in your current shell. So, for running this command with an custom aws profile in my case: "aws ecr get-login --region eu-central-1 --no-include-email --profile mfa" - change "mfa" with your profile name

Comment: If MFA enabled, Set your session-token -> 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/

Answer (score 154):

You must attach a policy to your IAM role.

I attached `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` and it worked.

Comment: I've found out that when 2FA is enabled there is no option to use the aws ecr get-login, once I've removed the 2FA from my account I got the authorization token.

Comment: @Y.Eliash how is 2FA disabled? Where do I find that window. AWS is huge.

Comment: For future readers - If your role only needs to read (not write or edit) then `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` is sufficient.

Comment: this violates aws best practices 101, you should definitely not allow full access to all repos, just give your role access to what it needs

Comment: AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicPowerUser did not work for me.  Changing permissions to AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess policy worked.

Comment: I tried using AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess and it did not work. Then I added AdministratorAccess and that worked. So they must have changed something. Obviously I don't want to give full admin access, but there's no way to know what permission is needed afaict.

Comment: I attached it to my user and it worked.

Comment: This works but I'm downvoting it because it's not the best answer as the policy is just too loose. I suggest folks refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/69856560/2596409

Comment: Unlike the other answers, this one is understandable what exactly to do. At least on my level of AWS knowledge... And it works...

Answer (score 41):

The user must have GetAuthorizationToken for all resources on ECR. To make the policy tight, you can grant all actions only to the desired registry and only the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken to all resources. Here is an example policy to attach to your user:

```
            {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Action": [
                            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                            "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                            "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                            "ecr:PutImage",
                            "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
                        ],
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Resource": "<REPOSITORY_ARN_HERE>"
                    },
                    {
                        "Action": [
                            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
                        ],
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Resource": "*"
                    }

                ]
            }
```

Comment: Finally a correct one with tight policy.

Comment: Here is an example ARN for a repository: "arn:aws:ecr:*:123456789012:repository/my-cool-repo". Also, it may help others if these ecr actions as well to the bottom identity based policy, if needed (otherwise, remove the extra comma that's there now):

 ```"ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"```

 ```"ecr:DescribeImages",```


  ```"ecr:BatchGetImage",```


  ```"ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"```

Comment: Great answer thanks. But there shouldn't be a comma after "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken".

Comment: @JurajMartinka, thanks for the heads up. Nice catch. It wasn't a problem for me because i used that as a python dict structure, so it just ignores comma after the last element.

Comment: I am downvoting, as I was NOT ABLE TO FIND HOW TO DO IT - at least from this answer neither from the official AWS messy documentation... The only one which really works (despite of it may NOT be the best practice) is the one with the AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess... It is typical corporate style - overcomplicating things for a sake of better security actually leads to lowering the security - another example of the same thing is the corporate password policy - EVERYONE constructs passwords according to very predictable patterns, just to be able to proceed and do the real work...

Answer (score 39):

Here is a full answer, after I followed all steps - I was able to use ECR

The error can have a few meanings:

1. You are not authorized because you do not have ECR policy attached to your user
2. You are not authorized because you are using 2FA and using cli is not secure unless you set a temporary session token
3. You provided invalid credentials

Here is **a list of all steps to get access** (including handling 2FA)

1. First of all, you have to **create** a policy that gives you access to GetAuthorizationToken action in ECR.
2. Attach this policy either to a user or a group (groups/roles are IMHO always better approach, my vote to roles, e.g. DevOps)
3. Make sure you have AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY set in your environment. I recommend to use aws folder with credentials and profiles separated.

**If you have 2FA enabled**

4. You need to generate session token using this command
   `aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn-of-the-mfa-device --token-code code-from-token`. `arn-of-the-mfa-device` can be found in your profile, 2FA section. Token, is generated token from the device.
5. Update aws credentails with received `AccessKeyId`, `SecretAccessKey`, and `SessionToken`. AWS recommends having either cron job to refresh token, which means if you are doing it you are testing things, your prod resources most likely do not have 2FA enabled. You can increase session by providing `--duration-seconds` but only up to 36 hours. A good explanation can be found at [authenticate-mfa-cli](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/authenticate-mfa-cli/)

This should do the job

Comment: When you provide an invalid AWS credential it will throw this error too

Comment: 2 FA was my culprit, thanks for the details answer!

Comment: This is the only answer that shows how to use AWS CLI without removing 2FA, thanks!

Comment: @jiří-křivánek yes will help to watch 3-4 walk along videos on youtube https://youtu.be/aHuCeLn72Lg?t=846 ;  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGgNyOkZEb0 and there more ... with varying accents and content

Answer (score 19):

I ended up using AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser as seemed a better option than Full Access. Here are the policies I found as of June 2019:
[image: Container Registry Permissions]

Comment: This helped really.

Comment: Just to fast "copy-paste" : AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess

Answer (score 13):

Just as it appears in the error description, I have to allow action "GetAuthorizationToken" in my policy.

```
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```

*Note: This is not my full policy but a subsection of Statement.*

Answer (score 8):

In case you are trying to pull images from a PUBLIC AWS repository, you must add the following user permissions to your policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecr-public:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "sts:GetServiceBearerToken"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
 ]  
}
```

Please see the full documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/public/public-repository-policies.html).

Comment: Thanks!, I have a public registry so instead of `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess` I had to add `AmazonElasticContainerRegistryPublicFullAccess`

Comment: Worked for me....

Answer (score 3):

This was my guy `EC2InstanceProfileForImageBuilderECRContainerBuilds`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with ECS when I tried to push my container in the repository.

To solve it, I attached to my IAM role this : `AmazonECS_FullAccess`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I have set the `permission boundary` only to s3 previously that causes the issue.

Removed the `permission boundary` ,it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
              - Effect: Allow
                Sid: VisualEditor2
                Action:
                  - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                  - ecr:BatchGetImage
                  - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
                Resource: "*"
```

Comment: This policy should be more secure inline with least privilege as Diogo suggested above